# События касания на мобильных браузерах

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется компонент Vue.js, где на Div весит обработчик событий мыши.
Идея в том что вложенные div реагируют на события провода над ними мыши при нажатой левой кнопке.

```
<div id="parent_id" @mousemove="onmove" @mousedown="ondown">
   <div>Div1</div>
   <div>Div2</div>
</div>
```

JS Код следующего вида

```
data() {
  mouseIsDown: false 
},
mounted() {
   window.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDown);
   window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUp);
}
methods() {
    mouseDown(event) {     
      this.mouseIsDown = true;     
    },

    mouseUp() {
      this.mouseIsDown = false;      
    },

    onmove(event) {
       if (this.mouseIsDown) {
          this.dosome(event.target);
       }
    },
    ondown(event) {
       if (this.mouseIsDown) {
          this.dosome(event.target);
       }     
    }

   dosome(target) {
     console.log(target.innerText);
   }
}
```

На мобильном браузере успешно отрабатывается нажатие, но событие mouseMove отсутствует. Как можно реализовать отлов события проведения нажатым касанием над элементом?

**UPD**
Решение.

```
   mounted() {
      ...
      // Навешиваем обработчик события на родительский элемент
      document
      .getElementById("parent_id")
      .addEventListener("touchmove", this.touchMove);
   }
   methods : {
      touchMove(event) {
         // получаем касание
         const touch = event.changedTouches[0];   
         // вычисляем нажатый дочерний элемент  
         const target = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
         // далее как обычно   
         this.dosome(target);
      }
   }
```

Comment: А на компьютере данный код работает? Мне кажется, должна быть потеря контекста вызова для `mouseDown` и `mouseUp`.

Comment: на компе все ок, события эти вешаются при создании на окно, и удаляются перед удалением компонента. Вопрос как "возюкание пальцем" и  отлов нажатых элементов реализовать на мобилке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мобильных устройствах нету `mouse*` событий.

Нужно отслеживать `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchcancel`, `touchmove`.

Работает так же, но в `TouchEvent` лежит массив (если вам, конечно, вам нужны координаты):

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
    console.log(e.touches);
}
```

Подобно можно почитать в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Comment: Во vue есть встроенные обработчики на мышь \@mousedown  \@click и т.д, а на тач выходит нету?

Comment: @Marat я не уверен, что нет встроенной поддержки, но точно есть библиотеки, которые добавляют поддержку [vue2-touch-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-touch-events)